# Prisma result processing into single object

Tags: javascript, mongodb, next.js, prisma

I'm working on a nextjs 13 project with prisma ORM with MongoDB. Currently I am trying to fetch roles with permissions for admin role matrix. This is the Role model schema.

```
model Role {
  id          String   @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  name        String   @unique
  userIDs     String[] @db.ObjectId
  users       User[]   @relation(fields: [userIDs], references: [id])
  permissions String[]

  @@map("roles")
}
```

When fetching the records I'd like to process them a little. Running this query returns such result.

```
const roles = await prisma.role.findMany({
    select: {
        name: true,
        permissions: true,
    }
})
console.log(roles);
```

```
 [
  { name: 'User', permissions: [ 'permissions.user.view.dashboard' ] },
  {
    name: 'Admin',
    permissions: [
      'permissions.admin.view.dashboard',
      'permissions.user.view.dashboard'
    ]
  }
]
```

I need the results in one object with role name prepended to the permission like so

```
{
    'User.permissions.user.view.dashboard',
    'Admin.permissions.user.view.dashboard',
    'Admin.permissions.admin.view.dashboard'
}
```

So my question is how would I do this? Preferably directly in prisma, but if it's not possible javascript will do.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to transform this object directly at Prisma level.
You can achieve this transformation like this:

```js
import { PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client';

const prisma = new PrismaClient();

async function main() {
  const roles = await prisma.role.findMany({
    select: {
      name: true,
      permissions: true,
    },
  });
  console.log(roles);

  const updatedRoles = [];

  roles.forEach((role) => {
    role.permissions.forEach((permission) => {
      updatedRoles.push(`${role.name}.${permission}`);
    });
  });

  console.log(updatedRoles);
}

main()
  .catch((e) => {
    throw e;
  })
  .finally(async () => {
    await prisma.$disconnect();
  });
```

Here's the sample response:
[image: terminal]